# How to fix "TypeError: connect() failed between NavigationToolbar2QT.message[str] and _show_message()" after Linux upgrade?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, qt5, typeerror, pyqt5

After upgrading my Fedora 24 to 25, I am having issue with running a python script which was running just fine under Fedora 24. No matter what I choose from that default list for `backend` in `matplotlibrc` file, I am not able to produce plots. In particular, when I choose `Qt5Agg` in that list for the `backend`, I am receiving this weird error message and it is really bothering that I cannot find any thing related to that on internet just by searching. But I am also aware that something in the upgrade could have gone wrong affecting my python and/or Qt packages. I just need to know why connectivity has to do with the choice of `backend` (if any at all)  and why none of the default choices can get rid of any sort of error message? But to be specific, why choosing `Qt5Agg` as the default `backend` of `matplotlibrc` file is giving such an error message related to the function `connect()`? Please let me know if posting the script would help you with the answer. Here is the imports in the beginning of that script:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
#import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
from uncertainties import ufloat
from uncertainties.umath import *
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from collections import OrderedDict
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.cosmology import FlatLambdaCDM, z_at_value
from numpy import sqrt, mean, square, std, maximum, minimum
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from scipy.stats import poisson, chi2
import math
import sys
```

And the error message:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect NavigationToolbar2QT::message(QString) to (null)::_show_message()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 496, in <module>                                                                                                                  
    f, ((ax1, ax6, ax11), (ax2, ax7, ax12), (ax3, ax8, ax13), (ax4, ax9, ax14), (ax5, ax10, ax15)) = plt.subplots(5, 3, sharex=True, sharey=False , figsize=(20,9))                             
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1177, in subplots                                                                                                          
    fig = figure(**fig_kw)                                                                                                                                                                      
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 527, in figure                                                                                                             
    **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 43, in new_figure_manager                                                                                 
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, thisFig)                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 51, in new_figure_manager_given_figure                                                                    
    return FigureManagerQT(canvas, num)                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 465, in __init__                                                                                             
    self.toolbar.message.connect(self._show_message)                                                                                                                                            
TypeError: connect() failed between NavigationToolbar2QT.message[str] and _show_message()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in that backend, exposed by more strict checking in PyQt 5.7.

It was [fixed in July](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/655c513a5e5440014677ee5afb08b0efa39f8e16) - I suggest you open a Fedora bug so they upgrade those packages or backport the fix.

As for why this happens: This is not related to connectivity as in network, but connecting of Qt's [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).